# Why does tab button on keyboard not working in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I am novice to android. I am trying a sample login application, everything working fine except 
see the below screen shot, where I have entered username field and now when I press `TAB` button on keyboard it works like a space. Any idea why the focus is not going to next field?

[image]

Comment: @ChiragRaval when tried enter button, the focus is moving to next filed, but as there are `two enter buttons` on keyboard the one in `numerical key` is not working, and also I want it to be generic I mean it should work with normal , `TAB`, `ARROW` etc keys!

Comment: you figure this out @sandip